# query to match a value in multiple ranges

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table as below:

```
promo_code  |   minimum_order   |   discount
------------+-------------------+-------------
100         |   10              |   10%
100         |   20              |   15%
100         |   30              |   20%
101         |   13              |   7%
102         |   8               |   10%
102         |   12              |   14%
```

In another table I have the sales in quantity and the promotions they are eligible

```
sales   |   promo_eligibility   |   record_id
--------+-----------------------+-------------
14      |   100                 |   1000
7       |   101                 |   1001
25      |   102                 |   1002
```

I need to get the discount that correspond to the sales volume and promotion...

as in the above examples:

```
record_id   |   discount    |   Comments
------------+---------------+--------------
1000        |   15%         |   (bigger than 10 and lower than 20)
1001        |   0%          |   (did not reached the minimum)
1002        |   14%         |
```

The number of thresholds could vary from 0 to 3

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the datatype of the *discount* field ... text or numeric?

Comment: Please explain why *record_id* 1000 is assigned a 15% *discount* instead of 10%.

Comment: @HansUp, in the comment the OP explains, as 14 > 10, but 14 < 20?

Comment: @PaulFrancis *record_id* 1000 has 14 for *sales*, which is below the *minimum_order* threshold (20) for the 15% *discount*.  So seems to me that one does not qualify for the 15% promotion, but does satisfy the *minimum_order* (10) for 10% *discount*.

Comment: I do agree. There needs some verbiage issue. From the data presented, and the result and comments, the word "minimum_order" is very misleading.

Comment: the minimum in the field refers to the minimum sales for the discount. its true it could be misleading... but the rule is as @paulfrancis said. Its between 10 and 20

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select 
  r.record_id,
  isnull(d.discount, '0%')
from records r
outer apply (
  select top 1 discount
  from discounts d
  where d.promo_code = r.promo_eligibility
  and d.minimum_order <= r.sales)
```

Comment: Note I would get 10% for the disputed order also... it doesn't qualify for the 15% discount.